# Sum of specific products in the opportunity

Tags: trigger, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

I have tried to figure out if there is a way to calculate the sum of specific products from opportunity products and display it in the opportunity object, but I haven't been very successful with that. Is that even possible? Will a trigger do the job?

Example:

**Opportunity-LineItem**

Product A (total price: $1.00)

Product B (total price: $2.00)

Product C (total price: $3.00)

Product D (total price: $4.00)

**Field in the opportunity object:**

- Product A&D: $5.00
- Product B&D: $6.00
- Product A&B: $3.00
- Product C&D: $7.00
- Product C&B: $5.00

Comment: I'd think you would be able to take care of this using a couple of rollup summary fields (RSF for short). Have you tried adding a filter to a RSF to control which `OpportunityLineItems` get included in that RSF?

Comment: You need to use trigger for this calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming only five combos, then 5 RSF fields will do the trick

- You will need to have a workflow copy the value of `OpportunityLineItem.PricebookEntry.Product.ProductCode` into a new custom field `OpportunityLineItem.ProductCode__c`. This is because RSF criteria can't reference cross object fields.  If the OLI contains the Product Code, then you can write the RSF criteria.
- Create five formula Checkbox fields `IsAD__c`, `IsBD__c`, ... that are true if `OpportunityLineItem.ProductCode__c` = `'A'` or = `'D'`, etc.
- RSF criteria for `Opportunity.AD__c` is sum of `OpportunityLineItem.TotalPrice` if `IsAD__c = true`
- Rinse and repeat for the other 4 combos